# (ANDROID) Toolbar Auto Clic

Tags: android

necesito una ayudadita. Estoy implementando un Toolbar donde con el onCreateOptionsMenu puedo inflar un menu que tiene 3 botones como refrescar , eliminar etc , Como podria hacer para que al entrar a esa actividad ya sea con el onOptionsItemSelected o con el  onCreateOptionsMenu o de cualquier otra forma, un boton del Toolbar se de clic automaticamente ya que el perfomanceClic no funciona , alguna sugerencia

Comment: ¿Quieres que *un boton del Toolbar se de clic automaticamente* si he leído bien? ¿Y por qué no lanzas la acción que invoca ese botón en el `onCreate` directamente? No me parece correcto desde ningún punto de vista tener una opción en el Toolbar para que se de click a ella misma  ¿?

Comment: quizas tenga razon y deba lanzarlo en un onCreate y solucionado el problema pero aun tengo esa duda existencial , hay forma de hacerlo ???

Comment: Un botón se coloca para que el usuario generalmente lo presione y a raíz de eso lanzar una acción, ¿estamos de acuerdo en eso? Programar un botón para que al entrar en una `Activity` se presione a sí mismo no tiene sentido, sería hasta una cosa de mal gusto, una aplicación zoombie que toma decisiones por sí misma. Poderse todo se puede, puedes hasta mostrar como un dedo fantasma presiona el botón si quisieras. Todo eso se lanzaría desde el `onCreate`, por tanto, ¿qué sentido tendría hacerlo de otra forma o intentar cosas raras? hay paradigmas en programación y conviene seguirlos.

Comment: totalmente de acuerdo contigo pero que te puedo decir , hay profesores que quieres ver el mundo arder y creeme es dificil hacerlo entonces con tipo de argumentos como los paradigmas de programacion , en fin muchas gracias por el tiempo en responderme!

Comment: Como te digo, si el profesor te pidió eso puedes hacerlo desde el `onCreate`, lanzas el código que invocaría el clic de ese botón. Y si quieres sorprender al profesor puedes hasta crear el efecto de clic del botón nada más lanzar la `Activity`. Pero hacer eso sigue siendo un sin sentido desde mi punto de vista.